# Navigation to screen with Flutter Hooks not working

Tags: flutter, navigation, hook, riverpod

Navigating from a button press to a screen with HookConsumerWidget or HookWidget gives an error: "Hooks can only be called from within the build method of a widget that mix-in hooks".

But I thought the button that navigates to the screen is already within the build method of the calling screen. I converted the calling screen to a HookWidget just in case that was the issue but no lukc as I get the same error. I am not understanding this error.

snippet in a stateless widget containing button to navigate:

```
_BackLayerButton(
                  icon: Icons.upload,
                  title: 'Upload Product',
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context)
                        .pushNamed(UploadProductScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),
```

UploadProducScreen that is final destination:

```
class UploadProductScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  static const routeName = 'uploadProductScreen';
  UploadProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final _file = useState<File?>(null);
  final _imageFile = useState<XFile?>(null);
  final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final category = ref.watch(categoryControllerProvider).productCategory;
    String _productTitle = '';
```

When I replace the above code with a simple Stateless widget, everything works. How can one navigate to a screen with Hooks via button pressed from another screen? Please help as I have tried everything I know to do. The same code works for stateless and stateful widgets for navigation but not for HookWidget. I need to use hooks for other features of the app so abandoning hooks is not my choice. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem identified and resolved after combing through the code line by line and by process of elimination. The error was specifically in regards to the HookWidget class (screen) that was called and not with the calling screen.
I found that a couple of final variables (eg emailTextEditingController) defined to utilize useTextEditingController() were defined outside of the build method of the widget. Once I relocate these variables appropriately to within the build method of the widget, the error went away and navigation happened as desired. Phew!!! This took me 3 days but thank God for the insight. I still have other open issues that I seriously need help with; e.g. animation not working using HookWidget but works in Stateful class.